# Ajax calender extender initially appears blank in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use this as my calender extender

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0" id="tblHIVtreatmentList">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkHIVtreatmentList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" Width="500" onclick='ShowPopUpforHivArt()'>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Treatment start date: 
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="textBox" ToolTip="Treatment Started Date" Width="100px" ID="txtHivTreatmentStartedDate"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="cetxtHivTreatmentStartedDate" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtHivTreatmentStartedDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add something more..

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I am using ajax calender  extender in my project it shows blank calendar when i click on the textbox

Comment: please answer me for this i am struck here

Comment: What version are you using? The demo page http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx is using `ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender` instead of `asp:CalendarExtender`

Comment: ajax control toolkit version 1

Answer (score -1):

In ScriptManger Tag just add ScriptMode="Release"